# Get the vertical Size of a UILabel which has more than one line?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel with more than one line:

```
let serviceDescription: UILabel = UILabel() serviceDescription.text =
"some very long text..." 
serviceDescription.numberOfLines = 0
serviceDescription.sizeToFit()
self.contentView.addSubview(serviceDescription)
```

Then I add some autolayout constraints:

```
serviceDescription.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
  make.top.equalTo(self.contentView_snp_top).offset(24)
  make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(20)
  make.right.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(-20)
}
```

Now I want to compute the size this label would need on the screen so I did:

```
let newSize: CGSize = serviceDescription.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
println("serviceDescription size: \(newSize)")
```

The result is:

```
(3408.0, 95.5)
```

I did all the preceding commands in viewDidLoad().

**How do I get the correct size of the label on screen?**

Comment: If you're using AutoLayout why do you need to figure out how much room you need for your label? It'll size itself.

Comment: It does not work as I described. There is no contentView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the height, the label knows its height after it has laid itself out,

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(label.frame.height) // 21
        label.text = "Some long text to make the text go over more than one line"
        label.layoutIfNeeded()
        println(label.frame.height) // 101.5
    }
```

Comment: What do I have to do to get the contentView being adjusted automatically?

Comment: @confile, the label needs to have constraints to the top and bottom of the content view to get it to expand with the label.

Comment: Inside my contentView I have one UIView and two UILabel. Which one do I have to layout how?

Comment: @confile, that is a different question from the one I answered. If you want help with that, you should ask a new question. You need to include how those UI elements are arranged inside the content view, and if you have any size constraints on any of them.

Comment: What is the difference between sizeToFit() and layoutIfNeeded()?

Comment: @confile In this situation, I don't think there is any practical difference. The label will size itself appropriately without calling `sizeToFit`, but not until another turn of the run loop; calling `layoutIfNeeded` forces it to layout right away so it logs correctly in the next line. I suppose there are situations where a view won't resize itself without calling `sizeToFit`, but I can't think of one off the top of my head.